# Associating user data with the data provided by REST API

Tags: json, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, frontend, rest

To gain a better understanding of React, I made a simple checklist app that allows you to track your in-game progress and take some notes related to it. The data is persisted in the form of a JSON object which is stored in the firebase real-time database. For a single user (myself) the application is working as intended, but I've no clue on how to allow multiple people to access the site and maintain their own checklists.

```js
{
  "items": [{
    "id": 0,
    "task": "Task to follow",
    "note": "Strategize",
    "isCompleted": false
  }, {
    "id": 1,
    "task": "Another task",
    "remark": "Wait for second playthrough",
    "isCompleted": true
  }]
}
```

The code snippet represents the checklist JSON object with mock data. Assuming that I manage to implement user authentication, how do I associate that signed-in user to the checklist data that is unique to them, as opposed to every user sharing the same checklist? For added context, users will be only allowed to alter the "note" and "isCompleted" properties. The optimal solution would be to persist data in MongoDB, but I would love to read some insights from you that will allow me to modify parts of the existing project, and not redo the entire thing.

Comment: you're using firebase, you can modify the shape of your data to be `> user id > rest of the data>`. that way you can access it

Comment: @ObedMarquezParlapiano Excellent solution to my problem. Thank you so much. Wouldn't this modification result in data duplication though? Assuming that there are 50 checklist objects, 10 users combined will have 500 unique objects. I'm new to this, so I would love to read your insight on this.

Comment: answered as a proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you're looking for is each logged in user having their own checklist, you can modify the structure of your store to look like this:

```
{ 'user-id-string-from-logged-in-hash': 
    {
      "items": [{
        "id": 0,
        "task": "Task to follow",
        "note": "Strategize",
        "isCompleted": false
      }, {
        "id": 1,
        "task": "Another task",
        "remark": "Wait for second playthrough",
        "isCompleted": true
      }]
     }
    }
```

That way you have each user isolated and easily accessible. You'll end up with a big database but that's completely fine. With firebase you're looking for a good structure and convenience rather than optimizing size, since firebase is extremely fast (it's like a look-up table).s

If instead you want to have a checklists shared and modified by multiple users, you can do something like:

```
{
  "items": [{
    "id": 0,
    "task": "Task to follow",
    "note": "Strategize",
    "isCompleted": false,
    "modifiedBy": ['hash-of-user': { < object with the type of modifications the user did or something >}]
  }, {
    "id": 1,
    "task": "Another task",
    "remark": "Wait for second playthrough",
    "isCompleted": true
    "modifiedBy": ['hash-of-user': { < object with the type of modifications the 
    user did or something >}]
  }]
}
```